# What happens to water after it reaches the triple point in a vacuum chamber?

Tags: thermodynamics

If you start to pull a vacuum on some room temperature liquid water it will start to boil, drop in temperature along the boiling line (on a phase diagram) until it reaches the triple point.

What happens afterwards, if you continue pulling the vacuum?

Does it continue on the sublimation line until all of it is sublimated off?
Also, is the process of dropping to the boiling line isothermic?

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: this is the phase diagram for water https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point#Triple_point_of_water .  For me it says that as the pressure falls water turns to vapor.